# .htaccess 301 redirect Homepage to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess

I would like to redirect my home page to a subdomain in .htaccess. Ive tried several different ways I found online. None have worked.

https://example.com/index.com to https://sub.example.com/index.com

Comment: Code below is how you would do it!

Comment: RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/sub\.example\.com\/" [R=301,L]

Comment: You should write your _answer_ as an "answer" in the box below (you can later accept it), rather than posting a _comment_.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you actually want to redirect *all* requests to that subdomain this probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://sub.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It probably makes sense to start using R=302 *temporary* redirections first. And to only change those to R=301 *permanent* redirections once everything works as desired. That prevents nasty caching issues on the client side. Also you always want to test using a fresh anonymous browser window.

Best place to implement such rules is in the central http server's host configuration. If you do not have access to that you can use a distributed configuration file instead (".htaccess"), if you have enabled the consideration of such files in the http server ... Above rules will work likewise if that file is placed inside the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder of the http host.

Comment: The OP would seem to want to redirect the "homepage" only, not every page.

Comment: @MrWhite That might or might not be the case. That is the issue with using vague terms like "homepage". I understood the question the way I answered it.